# Retorno com valores diferentes em JSON / PHP

Tags: php, sql, json

Cenário: Tenho uma query feita em PHP e preciso retorná-la para meu app iOS em formato JSON. Porém ao fazer alguns testes, no navegador, notei que ao usar a função `echo json_enconde($resultado);` retorna menos resultados na tela. Por exemplo, meu banco de dados possui cerca de 200 registros em uma coluna, mas usando o `json_encode`, só aparece alguns valores da coluna, e quando uso somente `echo`, retorna todos os resultados.

Alguém sabe por que há essa redução nos valores usando `json_encode`?

Abaixo está meu código em PHP:

```
include "conexao.php";   

// Pucha o conteudo do processo que fica na coluna todo_resto    
$sql = "select todo_resto from registros";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro .:" . mysql_error());

// Criando variável linha do tipo array
$linha = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_object($resultado))
{  
    $linha [] = $r->todo_resto; 
}

// Não funciona
// echo json_encode($linha);

// Não funciona
// print_r(json_encode($linha));

mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Após alguns testes fiz uma alteração no `while` do código ficando deste modo:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($resultado))
    {  
        echo ($r->todo_resto)."######";
    }
```

conseguindo imprimir todos os valores, porém quando insiro o `json_encode`, somente retorna alguns valores do banco, os demais ficam em branco (nulos).

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($resultado))
    {  
        echo json_encode($r->todo_resto)."#";
    }
```

Comment: Tenta substituir o `$r = mysql_fetch_object($resultado)` por `$r = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)`. E `$linha [] = $r->todo_resto;` por somente `$linha[] = $r;`

Comment: Vou tentar e ve se da certo!

Comment: Fiz as alterações sugeridas @claudsan, mas somente o print_r($linha); funciona. Mas nada com json_encode.

Comment: Editei o código da questão, fiz um novo teste no código.

Comment: vou tentar montar um exemplo igual ao teu aqui para tentar entender melhor. E volto aqui novamente.

Comment: Blz!! No banco de dados, a coluna tem as seguintes características: tipo: TEXT, Agrupamento (Collation): utf8_bin. Estou usando XAMP 1.8.3-5

Comment: da uma olhada aqui deu certo: http://arminio.com.br/teste.php e aqui http://arminio.com.br/teste.php?fonte a unica coisa que alterei foi a variavel $count.

Comment: você so fez a adição do $count para controlar o looping? Foi so isso?

Comment: sim, não vi nada de estranho na função, os seus dados são apenas texto? tem algum caracter especial? ou html dentro?

Comment: Amigo, copiei e colei seu codigo aqui, o count retornou para mim 817 registros, mas a tela fica em branco :/

Comment: Os dados são somente texto sim, so que são muitos :/

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18049/discussion-between-claudsan-and-tiago-amaral).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solução:

```
 <?php

include "conexao.php";   

mysql_set_charset('utf8'); //<--- SOLUÇÃO

// Pucha o conteudo do processo que fica na coluna todo_resto    
$sql = "select todo_resto from registros";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Erro .:" . mysql_error());

// Criando variável linha do tipo array
$linha = array();
$count = 0;
while($r = mysql_fetch_object($resultado))
{  
    $linha [$count] = $r->todo_resto; 
    $count++;

}
// FUNCIONA
echo "total: $count<hr><pre>\n\n";
echo json_encode($linha);


mysql_close(); 


?>
```

Referência: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: Otima solução, limpa rápida e eficiente!! @claudsan muito obrigado!!